# How to create data driven pages at a 1":100' scale covering entire network

Tags: arcmap, data-driven-pages

I am trying to create data driven pages at a 1":100' scale (1:1200 in Arcmap) that would fill several 11x17 sheets of paper. I am trying to use the Grid Index tool to create them, but it seems no matter what I do I always end up with just one giant rectangle despite specifying the scale, width, and height each grid feature should be. Not sure what else I can change in the settings to get this to work
[image]

Comment: Please add the corresponding tag of the software you're working with.

Comment: I have not tried Grid Index tool so I dont know what it does. But I think I have used [Create Fishnet](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm) to solve problems like this. Or are you trying to create each polygon of different sizes?